# 2005: A Space Oddity

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, video-games

It is the yea*r* 2005, in the land known as Los Angeles. Today was a very special day for the pe*o*ple known as "gamers". The *b*rand-new console, *Nitin Dozwich*, was set to releas*e* today.

As the "gamers" and "*r*eporters" took their seats in the auditorium for the grand unveiling, millions were *t*urning on their te*l*evision sets to watch.

The mic boomed.

> The *Dozwich* is the res*u*lt of 12 years of development. 12 years of non-stop work, researching and utilizing the latest technology possible. Yet, the team feels we are 12 years into the futu*r*e. Many believe we wasted 12 years, but we are actually 12 years ahead.

Everyone clapped.

> Now, for the live demonstration!

The projector turned on. The room was silent. There was no *Nitin Dozwich*. Rather, there was a peculiar error message.

[image: Error message]

The presenter started to speak.

> Than*k* you! Thank you! Soon, time will not stop anyone!

Everyone was shocked. What is this "error", and why is the pre*s*enter so happy?

More importantly, **What does this mean?**

---

Text Version

```
The Nitin Dozwich games
0303 [3,6,2,{_????},6,2,3,4]
0616 [{_???}]
0511 [{????????_}]
1221 [3,3,5,2,{???????_???}]
0404 [4,4,{_?????????}]
0829 [{??_??}+7,7,6]
0922 [3,4,7,5,5,{?_??}]

[ALL_SPELL] [?ISANY] [SPACE ODDITY]
```

Comment: There is one "clue" that is not part of the puzzle, but rather a sneak peek of sorts. P̵͘҉̧͝r̵̛҉͞ę̶̕̕p̶̀͢͠a͠ŕ͞͏̀e͞͏̶̛҉ ̨̡́͜f́̕͡͡ơ̵͝͝r̴̀͝҉ ͝a̡҉̨ ̨͏̡҉w̛͠͠o̶̷̕͡r҉̴l̷d̴̢́͢͢ ͝҉̛m͏̶̧͜a̷̶̧d̸̨̕é͝ ҉̕͟͞f̛͞͡r̵̨͘͘͡é̢́͡ę̷̨̧.̷̷

Comment: Prepare for a world made tree?

Comment: Prepare for a world made free I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured out many of the clues but can't put them together. Here is what I have found so far.

> The first thing I noticed is that Nitin Dozwich is basically Nintendo Switch, which was released in 2017 or 12 years after 2005.
>
>  Next I saw the italicized letters. Combining them we get "robert lurks".
>
>  Now to the error message. It starts out saying The nintendo switch games and the first one I thought of was "The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild". I noticed the word lengths matched the numbers in the first line and 0303 matches the release date (March 3rd). From this we see (with hints in the greyed out buttons) that z is the indicated letter. So, here are the rest of the games that fit (note that the north american release date is used):
>
>  The Legend of (Z)elda Breath of the Wild
>  (A)rms
>  Minecraf(t)
>  Max The Curse of Brother(h)ood
>  Lego City (U)ndercover
>  Ma(r)io + Rabbids Kingdom Battle
>  The Lego Ninjago Movie Video G(a)me
>
>  The indicated letters spell out Zathura as in the movie Zathura: A Space Adventure released in 2005.
>
>  Here is where I am stuck. I'm not sure how all the clues come together. It definitely involves Zathura somehow. I'm not sure if the David Bowie song Space Oddity is relavant and I have no clue what the Robert Lurks clue relates to.

Comment: Wow, so quick! The answer is supposed to be Zathura, following the general theme of movies as answers in my puzzles. R͏̵́͟͜ó̸̵b̧̛ę͟͜͝ŗ̷̷͝t̡̡͘͢͟ ̷͞w̛i̡̛ĺ̨̛͜ĺ̕ ̷̧͟b̶͝ŕi͘͢n̴͘͢͟͞g̨̀͠ ̸̵̀ş̸̀͘͝a̶l̵̶͟͟͡v̷̛̛͢͞a̸̢̧͠t̢͝i̶̛̛͘͢ò̴̀͟͠n̛.҉̕͝͠

Comment: Ok, I guess I was missing the context of your other questions